# Text input layout in collapsingToolbarLayout using support library

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Why is it that when i try to put the text input layout in the collapsing toolbar layout, nothing seems to appear.

**Here is my code**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="200dp"
                   android:src="@null"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                           android:layout_gravity="top"
                                           android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                       android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                                                       android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="40dp"
                    />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I'm using support library v23

**EDITED**

I also tried moving the textInputLayout below the collapsing toolbar layout but no positive results.

Comment: try to put it after the closing of `CollapsingToolbarLayout` tag.

Comment: I tried it but no positive results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextInputLayout is for EditText not for TextView so replace your TextView with EditText or Copy this code and try again.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="#ff00" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:text="Number"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <!-- Your toolbar should always below your View otherwise it won't be visible  -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@null"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:inputType="number"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```